# 5V FTDI cable for Arduimu V3

Tags: ftdi

I just recently bought an Arduimu v3. Rather annoyingly they did not supply an FTDI cable. I'm going for an FTDI cable where the I/O pins are configured to operate at 5v. I assume this is the right but I don't want to fry this board. Is this cable OK?

Comment: The board is a 5v one, so a 5v FTDI would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 5V cable would be fine, or for about the same price, I would recommend an [Adafruit FTDI Friend](http://www.adafruit.com/product/284) which is configurable between 5V and 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the board is 5V